# what is the best way to change a gem locally and then revert changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to write some puts statements to gem files, but I am afraid that I may forget to revert my changes. But I still want the ability to change gems locally and then restore their original versions. I am using bundler and gemsets for different rails projects. One way to do so is to store which gem i changed, uninstall it and then reinstall it. Other way is to create a temporary gemset, import all gems needed, make changes to it, and then destory the temporary gemset. what are other ways to change gems locally and fast, and to get the original gem once done with debugging?

Answer (score 1):

use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). It allows you to make a savepoint on your files, make some changes, and rollback to an earlier version if something goes wrong. There are many other features, but it would be too long to describe here.